# Getting the facebookconnect to work with Visual Studio 2013 - CTP3

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

For a couple of days now I have been struggling to get the “facebookconnect”-plugin to work with Visual Studio 2013 Cordova CTP3. I have addED it as a custom plugin within config.xml. I tried the 0.10.1 and 0.11 version, but the problem remains the same. I have also edited the config.xml and added the additional:

```
<param name="APP_ID" value="12345678" />
<param name="APP_NAME" value="My Facebook App" />
```

What happened after it gets installed is that it seems to disappear from the installed plugin overview right after. The green checkmark also disappear.  This repeats every time I try to add it.

When I try to build the solution it tells me:

```
Warning 1   Unable to remove directory "bld\Debug\plugins". Could not find a part of the path 'facebookConnectPlugin.js'.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets   204 5   TestApp
```

Has anyone managed to get the facebookconnect plugin to work within CTP3 or know of any another method that would work? Help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Best regards
Duft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used openFB with Cordova and would recommend this over other solutions https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB

Comment: Hi unobf, thank you! This looks very promising. My project builds  like a charm now. I can see the GIT projects doesn't have a plugin.xml, which I have tried to build manual. I have tried to set cordova.require and call openfb.login, but it does not look like it gets included. However it is within the bld/plugin/... Do you have an example on a plugin.xml or how openfb could be called from index.js?

Comment: just include the openfb.js file as a normal script tag in your index.html